# How to get an Error Image when the password and confirm password fields arent't matched against each other

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I am working on this piece of code and need help with the Coding and Form Design in Visual Studios. I need assistance on writing the code or figuring out what Toolbox control I need to use to have a circle with an "!" in the middle next to confirm password if the password field and confirm password field do not match up. I am not sure what to do to get this image to appear. It will not let me post a picture, but all I need is on the form for it to have a ref exclamation point to the left of it if the password and the confirm password do not match up. The instructions are below.

> The password and confirm password fields need to be matched against each other, both when the page is submitted and also when the confirm password field has lost focus. If the form is not valid then the page will not be processed as described below. The password fields need to mask the password.

I have posted all the code I have done for this project so far, but all I really need help with is the conf password error symbol. I just decided to post all the code because I did not have much code for the password section.

```
namespace Forms
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void passwordTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        passwordTxt.PasswordChar = 'x';
        passwordTxt.MaxLength = 11;
    }

    private void confPassTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        confPassTxt.PasswordChar = 'x';
        confPassTxt.MaxLength = 11;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        majorBox.Items.Add("Math");
        majorBox.Items.Add("Science");
        majorBox.Items.Add("English");
        majorBox.Items.Add("Philosophy");
        majorBox.Items.Add("History");
    }

    private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstNameTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameTxt.Text)
           || string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNameTxt.Text) ||
           string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(confPassTxt.Text)
           || string.IsNullOrEmpty(majorBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(specialtyBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter in all fields before moving forward");
        }
    }

    private void majorBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (majorBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Math")
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Calculus");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Statistics");
        }
        else if (majorBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Science")
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Biology");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Chemestry");
        }
        else if (majorBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("18th Centruy");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Teacher");
        }
        else if (majorBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Philosophy")
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Aristotal");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Socrates");
        }
        else
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Peace");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("War");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any image has to be encapsulated by a control. See if the box you're working with supports an imbedded image, otherwise have to add the control on the form (I guess. I'm a long time mfc programmer, not C# yet). Why the _regex_ tag ?